# Add security property to OPENJDK docker configuration

Tags: java, docker

I am trying to disable TLS 1 and 1.1 in my docker instances along with disabling several algorithms for security purposes.  However I am trying to figure out how to add the below to properties to the /java/security folder of an alpine OPENJDK docker image?

jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 2048
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, TLSv1, DESede, DES, MD5, TLSv1.1, DH keySize < 2048

Above are the two properties I would normally add to my JAVA_HOME/java/security properties file to disable the algorithms and TLS versions through a non-dockerized approach.  But how would I pass this to the AlpineOPENJDK container I am deploying my java app in?

Comment: Figure out what its `$JAVA_HOME` is (it will be fixed for a given base image) and copy or patch the file in your `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the Dockefile like so:

```sh
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ADD path/to/project/java.security ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a project where the database was an old SQL Server which used TLS1.0 and in Java 17 it is disabled by default since it's no longer considered safe. I modified the `java.security` file on my machine to accept TLS1.0 and then pulled the `openjdk:17` image to create a docker container with the same version of Java (or at least a compatible one). My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:17
WORKDIR /
ADD backend.jar backend.jar
ADD java.security usr/java/openjdk-17/conf/security/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -jar backend.jar
```

I took the modified `java.security` file that accepted TLS1.0 and overrided the one in the container. After that this was shown in the console `TLSv1 was negotiated. Please update server and client to use TLSv1.2 at minimum.` which means that the connection was done and the application started successfully.